# Unix Command to parse 2 characters after dot

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a .txt file (t1.txt) with values per below. Each set of values. What I need to do is go through each line and parse out the first 2 characters after the first dot in Unix.

```
SBX00.GIATIC.-
SBX00.TIATIC.TTT.FAS.-
SBX00.SIATIC.SSBSC.CAMI.CRDT,SBX00.GIATIC.SSBSC.CAMI.ISITE
GB400.VIATIC.VQ051.CV750T1.D-,SB400.GIATIC.VQ051.CV902T1.D-,SB400.GIATIC.VQ051.CV902S1.D.-
```

I would want the new file to look like:

```
GI
TI
SI,GI
VI,GI,GI
```

Comment: So, the file has comma-separated fields.  Within each field, you want the two characters after the first dot.  Is that correct?  What have you tried?  What didn't work?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sed -e 's/[^,.]*\.\(..\)[^,]*/\1/g' myfile.txt
```

A test:

```
echo "GB400.VIATIC.VQ051.CV750T1.D-,SB400.GIATIC.VQ051.CV902T1.D-,SB400.GIATIC.VQ051.CV902S1.D.-" \
| sed -e 's/[^,.]*\.\(..\)[^,]*/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
VI,GI,GI
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` method you can use,

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s",substr($i,index($i,".")+1,2); printf NF==i?"\n":","}}' myfile.txt
GI
TI
SI,GI
VI,GI,GI
```

Brief explanation:

1. `-F,`: set the field separator as ','
2. `substr($i,index($i,".")+1,2)`: extract 2 char behind '.' for each field
3. `printf NF!=i?",":"\n"`: print '\n' if it is the last field, print ',' otherwise.